# Complexity of a particular integer knapsack version

Tags: complexity-theory

I need to know if the following problem is $NP$-complete.

The data are as follows :

- $n$, number of items
- $\{s_{i}\}_{i \in \{1, \dots n\}}$, item sizes, sorted by ascending values.
- $S$ knapsack capacity.
- $T$ a lower bound on the value to be attained.

Now, for each $i \in \{1, \dots n\}, c_i = \log i $ is the value of item $i$. 
The same item may be picked any number of times.

The question is : if we note for each $i \in \{1, \dots n\}$, $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$, the number of times item $i$ is picked, does a set of values for all $x_i$ exist such that :
$$
\forall i \in \{1, \dots n\}, x_i \in \mathbb{N},
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_ix_i \leq S
$$
and 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log i \cdot x_i \geq T
$$
?

A reduction from the subset sum problem doesn't look straightforward.